# Align text in multiple rotated multicolumns

Tags: tables, graphics, rotating, multicolumn

I have a table with figures and rotated text in the first two columns. I don't understand 2 issues:

1. How I can align and especially center the text? With the images I included (all same size and quadratic, scaled such that they fit the page) the text is not centered but bound left (2nd column) and aligned seemingly random (1st column).
2. How are the gaps between the rows determined? Right now not all are equally wide. If I use a smaller fontsize in the first line's option, the gaps are equal?!

I've tried playing with the options but I'm stuck now, help would be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
              & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\nu=-2\%$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\nu=0\%$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\nu=10\%$}\\
                \hline
    \parbox[t]{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Case A}}} & \rotatebox[origin=left]{90}{Value} &
            \includegraphics{Tux.png} & \includegraphics{test.png} & \includegraphics{test.png} \\
& \rotatebox[origin=left]{90}{Value change}  & \includegraphics{test.png} & \includegraphics{test.png} & \includegraphics{test.png} \\
    \parbox[t]{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Case B XYZ}}} & \rotatebox[origin=left]{90}{Value} & \includegraphics{test.png} & \includegraphics{test.png} & \includegraphics{test.png} \\
& \rotatebox[origin=left]{90}{Value change}  & \includegraphics{test.png} & \includegraphics{test.png} & \includegraphics{test.png}
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Value }
        \label{tab:num12}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your test file generates the error ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.12 ...2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Case A}}} &
  please fix

Comment: The error is `\parbox[t]{\multirow` but hard to guess what you intended `\multirow` can not be in a `\parbox` and a `\parbox` needs a width argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that may be useful.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc*{3}{C{0.25\textwidth}}}
              & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\nu=-2\%$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\nu=0\%$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\nu=10\%$}\\
                \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\centering Case A}}} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[t]{1cm}{Value}} &
            \includegraphics[width=1cm]{Tux.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png} \\
& \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\centering Value change}}  & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png} \\
    \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\centering Case B XYZ}}} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[t]{1cm}{Value}} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png} \\
& \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\centering Value change}}  & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png} & \includegraphics[width=3cm]{test.png}
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Value }
        \label{tab:num12}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to adjust the width of each `\parbox`, adjust the width of image in `\includegraphics` and in the column `C{0.25\textwidth}` to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much! What do you think about realizing the same with a minipage? like `\begin{rotate}{90}\begin{minipage}{2.8in}\begin{center}Case A\end{center}\end{minipage}\end{rotate}`